# Parsing subtags XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have this XML:

```
<SwitchPort name="1110" portType="RS422_Board2">
<Bus>UO-2-3</Bus>
<Device>FC3</Device>
<Appearance>Simulated</Appearance>
</SwitchPort>
```

I can get the portType using:

```
for node in NCFile.getElementsByTagName("SwitchPort"):
    portType = node.getAttribute("portType")
```

But I want to get the values of Apperance, Device, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `getElementsBytagName` on your `node` and get the `nodeValue`

```
for node in NCFile.getElementsByTagName("SwitchPort"):
    portType = node.getAttribute("portType")
    device = node.getElementsByTagName("Device")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    appearance = node.getElementsByTagName("Appearance")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

Comment: for node in NCFile.getElementsByTagName("SwitchPort"):
 portType = node.getAttribute("portType")
 print(portType)
 #device = node.getElementsByTagName("Device")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
 #appearance = node.getElementsByTagName("Appearance")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
 #print(appearance)

Comment: Thank you Rafael: But now I just get a limited number of the data that I want.       for node in NCFile.getElementsByTagName("SwitchPort"):
 portType = node.getAttribute("portType")
 print(portType)
 #device = node.getElementsByTagName("Device")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
 #appearance = node.getElementsByTagName("Appearance")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
 #print(appearance)

Comment: @M.Pickard sorry, its hard to understand your comments? Could you edit the post  ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use lxml for parsing xml - [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

> from lxml import etree
>
> root_element = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
>
> device_node_value = root_element.findtext('Device')